# sparkSession throwing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to write simple scala program to use spark, which has following content.

`src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.util.random

object SimpleApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "<Some Valid Text File Path>" // Should be some file on your system
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
```

but when I run the program I get following exception stack trace:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/03/21 03:23:07 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsRegistry.<init>(MetricsRegistry.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.<init>(MetricsSystemImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.<init>(MetricsSystemImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:9)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

I tried running in debug mode and exception seems to be thrown when trying to create SparkSession object. What am I missing?
I have installed spark from brew and it works from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. To run this in IDE I needed to add few extra dependencies. I appended following to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "28.2-jre"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.10.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.2"
```